# How to load an image from sdcard to a customized listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, android-sdcard, simpleadapter

I tried to load a photo to my customized list view that which is filled by using HashMap.

a part of code that is engaged is here...

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+/path/Cache/photo.png");
FileInputStream is = null; 
try { 
is = new FileInputStream(f); 
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.i("file not found","not found");
} 
Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
//Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeFile((PATH + "resene.png"));
map.put(TAG_PICTURE, bmp );
// adding HashList to ArrayList
paintShopsList.add(map);
```

and using simpleadapter to fill the listview

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ShopSearchActivity.this,
    paintShopsList, R.layout.list_row_search_shop, new String[] 
            {TAG_PICTURE},
    new int[] {R.id.list_image });
// updating listview

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

if i use drawable to put an image to hashmap it works but when i want to put image from SdCard this error occured

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you added permissions to read from external storage?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using new input stream, try:
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri))